# Is there a Python function to solve generalized eigenvalue problems, s.t. the returned eigenvectors are orthonormal wrt a mass matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I need to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem of the form

```
K @ v = w * M @ v
```

(where K and M are real symmetric matrices and w is an eigenvalue to the eigenvector v).
I can do this using `W, V = scipy.linalg.eig(K, b=M)`. However, I would also like the returned vectors in `V` to be orthonormal wrt to the scalar product induced by matrix M (in my case, a mass matrix). That is, I would like

```
V.T @ M @ V
```

to be close to the identity. Is there any fast and clean option for that in scipy/numpy etc, or is the only way to implement some Gram-Schmidt scheme oneself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.linalg.eigh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html).

For example,

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from scipy.linalg import eigh

In [3]: K = np.array([[4, 0, -1, 3], [0, 3, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 9, -2], [3, 1, -2, 9]])

In [4]: M = np.array([[14, 0, 3, 1], [0, 16, -1, 4], [3, -1, 10, 5], [1, 4, 5, 8]])

In [5]: evals, V = eigh(K, M)

In [6]: evals
Out[6]: array([0.18497917, 0.20745448, 0.50002279, 3.90342693])

In [7]: V
Out[7]: 
array([[-0.05899209, -0.25680325, -0.01369778, -0.08501946],
       [-0.25120648,  0.03191235, -0.01667211,  0.13305264],
       [ 0.00744091, -0.02271455,  0.19957286,  0.37023263],
       [ 0.03366447,  0.08755881,  0.1831409 , -0.44242341]])
```

Verify that `V.T @ M @ V` is approximately the identity:

```
In [8]: print(V.T @ M @ V)
[[ 1.00000000e+00  5.55111512e-17 -6.93889390e-17 -8.32667268e-17]
 [ 8.32667268e-17  1.00000000e+00 -9.71445147e-17  1.38777878e-16]
 [-3.46944695e-17 -5.55111512e-17  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [-1.38777878e-16  1.24900090e-16  1.66533454e-16  1.00000000e+00]]
```

That last result is a bit easier to read if we suppress the tiny values:

```
In [9]: with np.printoptions(suppress=True):
   ...:     print(V.T @ M @ V)
   ...: 
[[ 1.  0. -0. -0.]
 [ 0.  1. -0.  0.]
 [-0. -0.  1.  0.]
 [-0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Comment: Wow thank you, that's exactly what I need! So basically `scipy.linalg.eigh` returns different eigenvectors than `scipy.linalg.eig`? But then I guess this matrix scalar product only makes sense for symmetric matrices anyway...

Comment: The eigenvectors returned by `eig` and `eigh` are "different" in that they might be different bases for the same eigenspaces (and they might be returned in a different order, corresponding to a different order of the eigenvalues).  If the eigenvalues are all simple, then the difference will just be the lengths of the eigenvectors: `eig` normalizes the eigenvectors to have length 1, while `eigh` does not.  So for the `eig`, `V.T @ M @ V` will be a diagonal matrix, but not necessarily the identity.